# xargs and sed to extract specific lines

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

I want to extract lines that have a particular pattern, in a certain column. For example, in my 'input.txt' file, I have many columns. I want to search the 25th column for 'foobar', and extract only those lines that have 'foobar' in the 25th column. I cannot do:

```
grep foobar input.txt
```

because other columns may also have 'foobar', and I don't want those lines. Also:

1. the 25th column will have 'foobar' as part of a string (i.e. it could be 'foobar ; muller' or 'max ; foobar ; john', or 'tom ; foobar35')
2. I would NOT want 'tom ; foobar35'
3. The word in column 25 must be an exact match for 'foobar' (and ; so using awk $25=='foobar' is not an option.

In other words, if column 25 had the following lines:

1. foobar ; muller
2. max ; foobar ; john
3. tom ; foobar35

I would want only lines 1 & 2.

How do I use xargs and sed to extract these lines? I am stuck at:

```
cut -f25 input.txt | grep -nw foobar | xargs -I linenumbers sed ???
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use xargs and sed, use the other tool common on so many machines and do this:

```
awk '{if($25=="foobar"){print NR" "$0}}' input.txt
```

`print NR` prints the line number of the current match so the first column of the output will be the line number.
`print $0` prints the current line. Change it to `print $25` if you only want the matching column. If you only want the output, use this:

```
awk '{if($25=="foobar"){print $0}}' input.txt
```

EDIT1 to match extended question:
Use what @shellter and @Jotne suggested but add string delimiters.

```
awk -vFPAT="([^ ]*)|('[^']*')" -vOFS=' ' '$25~/foobar/' input.txt
```

`[^ ]*` matches all characters that are not a space.
`'[^']*'` matches everything inside single quotes.

EDIT2 to exclude everything but `foobar`:

```
awk -vFPAT="([^ ]*)|('[^']*')" -vOFS=' ' "\$25~/[;' ]foobar[;' ]/" input.txt
```

`[;' ]` only allows `;`, `'` and  in front and after foobar.

Tested with this file:

```
1 "1 ; 1" 4
2 'kom foobar' 33
3 "ll;3" 3
4 '1; foobar' asd
7 '5 ;foobar' 2
7 '5;foobar' 0
2 'kom foobar35' 33
2 'kom ; foobar' 33
2 'foobar ; john' 33
2 'foobar;paul' 33
2 'foobar1;paul' 33
2 'foobarli;paul' 33
2 'afoobar;paul' 33
```

and this command `awk -vFPAT="([^ ]*)|('[^']*')" -vOFS=' ' "\$2~/[;' ]foobar[;' ]/" input.txt`

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to add one more condition. The specified column will have 'foobar' as part of a string (i.e. it could be 'foobar ; muller' or 'foobar ; john ; david'

Comment: as above, but `$25 ~ /foobar/` should do it. Good luck.

Comment: jhamfler: I tried your last command, with your input.txt file, but my shell (on a mac) gives an error "awk: invalid -v option"

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the line with `foobar` as part of the 25 field.

```
awk '$25=="foobar"' input.txt
```

`$25` 25th filed
`==` equal to
`"foobar"`
Since no action spesified, print the complete line will be done, same as {print $0}

Or

```
awk '$25~/^foobar$/' input.txt
```

Comment: My mistake! Also 'foobar' must be an exact word match (so 'foobar35 ; tom' should not be selected. I have edited the original post to reflect the constraint!

Comment: @brian Updated answer

Comment: Jotne, thanks for your help! Will this ( /^foobar$/ )ensure that the line "max ; foobar ; john" is selected?

Comment: @brian No, it make sure field is only this.  If there field contains other stuff, you need to post enough example and we can test it out.  Eks it will select ok here`test data foobar more` if tested against 4rth field.  But fails here `test ; more ; foobar data ; extra ` since field 4 contains more than just foobar

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/\S+/\n&\n/25;s/\n(.*foobar.*)\n/\1/p' file
```

Surround the 25th field by newlines and pattern match for `foobar` between newlines.

If you only want to match the word `foobar` use:

```
sed -En 's/\S+/\n&\n/25;s/\n(.*\<foobar\>.*)\n/\1/p' file
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I might be almost there. Could you please explain the logic in the statement. Also, I get an error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string

Comment: @brian if `\S` is not recognised I doubt you are using GNU sed. However you can substitute `[^[:space:]]+` for `\S+`. The logic is to isolate the 25th field by surrounding it by newlines (which cannot exist as sed uses them to delimit the lines). Then pattern match using a regexp which begins and ends in newlines with `foobar` in between. As the `-n` is switched on, meaning explicit printing, only those lines that match the final substitution will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!